# debug.log is not created

Tags: debug

logs seem only while admin panel is loading,after page was loaded, it will hide so I cant seem the logs.Also I want to debug.log but there is no the file in wp-content.

```
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’, true );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

I gave 777 permission to wp-content but it doesnt work.

edit:

I found error_log file just now.It contains these lines:

```
[07-Mar-2020 21:14:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=1649106 in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2030
[07-Mar-2020 21:14:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=1649106 in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2030
[12-Mar-2020 11:59:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mytheme_meta_box_nonce in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/functions.php on line 330
[12-Mar-2020 11:59:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mytheme_meta_box_nonce in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/functions.php on line 330
[12-Mar-2020 11:59:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mytheme_meta_box_nonce in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/functions.php on line 330
[12-Mar-2020 11:59:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mytheme_meta_box_nonce in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/functions.php on line 330
[12-Mar-2020 15:36:51 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’ - assumed '‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 83
[12-Mar-2020 15:36:51 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’ - assumed '‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 84
[12-Mar-2020 15:37:51 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’ - assumed '‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 83
[12-Mar-2020 15:37:51 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’ - assumed '‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 84
[12-Mar-2020 15:37:59 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’ - assumed '‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 83
[12-Mar-2020 15:37:59 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’ - assumed '‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 84
[12-Mar-2020 15:39:51 Europe/Minsk] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’ - assumed '‘WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/deniztas/migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-config.php on line 83
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line 3 and 4's quotes and give a try.

```
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
 define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```